# How to identify source, destination ip using STUN and DTLS protocols?

Tags: udp, wireshark, packet-capture, packet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg4Vj.png)

Given image i'm not able to identify which is source and destination ip address ( client or server). From STUN protocol 1st packet it's user request so i thought 131.202.240.150 is client ip address. From DTLS 5th packet Client hello i thought 131.202.240.87 is client ip address. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "client" and "server"?

Comment: client here means the host who is requesting service(my machine ).

Comment: You already know who the server is! So why do you not know who the client is?

Comment: this is taken from  opensource dataset and captured on the computer whoever took this captures. Now i want to know his ip address through dtls, stun protocol. The client and server were both in same network. But i want to know the ip address of computer on  which this  captures are taken.

Comment: It is not possible to know that by looking at the capture. It may be neither of them. You will have to ask whoever made the capture.

Comment: Why not. client and server can easily be distinguised if it was Tcp protocol by SYN flag. why can't through dtls, stun both have some features over it.

Comment: You keep asking completely different questions! Please take a moment to think about what it is you actually want to know.

Comment: no my question remains same to get client and server ip addresses from given capture. client is who requests first something. if the capture was tcp. then syn flag denotes the request sent by client to make a connection. then the source (client) can be easily identified. Similarly i am asking to distinguish client , server  based on those dtls, stun protocols. Client can be simply defined as who initiates request. Kindly see the image shared through link

Comment: It is completely obvious from the image which host initiated the DTLS traffic, so I'm not sure why you asked this question at all.

Comment: from STUN protocol i can see the other host initiated the stun traffic.

Comment: Hmm. You seem to be assuming that this capture is _complete_, and that is not a safe assumption. There may have been traffic that took place prior to starting the capture. And the STUN traffic doesn't matter anyway.